# How to choose the boot loader?

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

I have a Dell G7 laptop and want to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I followed this steps, to install with a USB stick

1- I changed the BIOS to allow booting from the USB stick

2 - I put an ISO stick, which I built on this site (https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)
For:
Ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64

3 - I restarted and chose the option
Install Ubuntu

4 - I selected the language

5 - I selected the keyboard layout

6 - I selected the wifi network

7 - I chose a Minimal Install / Download updates while installing / Install 3rd party software

8 - In installation type I chose Erase Disk and reinstall Ubuntu

9 - I have two discs in this notebook - I selected sdb to delete and reinstall

10 - Trim the message: The following partitions will be formatted - SCSI2 (0,0,0) (sdb) partition # 1 as ext4

11 - I chose my geographic region

12 - I entered my username and password

13 - Installation continues until when it arrives at Running "grub-install / dev / sda" error appears: Unable to install GRUB on dev / sda - This is a fatal error.

14 - When I press OK a window asks:
- Choose another device to install boot loader
- Continue without a boot loader
- Cancel installation

15 - In the first option I selected / dev / sdb - but the same error appeared. Then I chose / dev / sdb1 - the same error continued

Please does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Comment: Is this an UEFI mode install or Legacy BIOS install? Does one of the drives have an EFI system Partition (ESP)? What is in `/dev/sda`?

Comment: Do you want the device `/dev/sdb` to work as a stand-alone drive, or is it OK to have the bootloader in `/dev/sda` (and I guess share it with the operating system in that drive)? Also, it makes things much easier, if you install Ubuntu in the same boot mode (UEFI or BIOS alias CSM alias legacy mode) as the operating system in `/dev/sda`.

Comment: Thank you @user68186 I use Legacy External Device. I don't know how to check if the drives have an EFI system Partition. Do you know how I can see this?

Comment: Post this above in question with formatting. `sudo parted -l` Use Ubuntu live installer in live mode and open terminal to run command. If sda if gpt then Windows will be UEFI, if MBR(msdos) then Windows will be BIOS. To ascertain the type of Platform Firmware on a Windows 8 computer, open Run ( WinKey+ R ), type "msinfo32" and click OK. 
This opens the System Information window. Select System Summary (on the left panel) and check for the Items "BIOS Mode" and "Secure Boot State". The BIOS Mode can be UEFI/Legacy, and the Secure Boot State - On/Off if UEFI Mode, Unsupported - Legacy Mode.